# Android Development - Code for clicking one list view to another

Tags: android, listview, click

I simply want to create a ListView containing "a","b","c".  When I click on each item, I want each item to direct a unique activity, each containing a different ListView.

Listview

- A

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
- B

  - 3
  - 4
  - 5
- C

  - 6
  - 7
  - 8

Please provide the best code for this.  Its so hard to find something on here that does this.  Most entries are too specific for me to get a clear understanding of how to do all this in the most consistent, efficient manner.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are describing an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). There are many tutorials to get you started, [like this one](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/), but everyone is different so it's impossible to give you "the best code for a clear understanding".

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for your response.  I do not want an expandable/collapsible ListView.  I simply want a different screen from the ListView to the next ListView.

Comment: Oh i see where you are coming from, Sam.  The hierarchy was meant to demonstrate items in the first list view ABC.  If A is selected open up a new screen containing another ListView with items 123.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a ListView with A, B, C in one Activity and the sublists in another Activity, you really only need one generic ListActivity to handle this. You only have to pass the ListActivity different sets of data.

In the `onCreate()` below:

- If the Activity is not passed special data it will display A, B, C and it will use the `onListItemClick()` method to start the sub-Activities.
- If the Activity does have the extra data stored in the Intent, then it displays this extra data in the ListView and will ignore any calls to `onListItemClick()`.

```java
public class Example extends ListActivity {
    boolean isSubList = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] array;
        Intent received = getIntent();
        // Setup as main ListView
        if(received == null || !received.hasExtra("array")) {
            array = new String[] {"A", "B", "C"};
        }
        // Setup as sub ListView
        else {
            isSubList = true;
            array = received.getStringArrayExtra("array");
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        if(!isSubList) {
            Intent starting = new Intent(Example.this, Example.class);
            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                starting.putExtra("array", new String[] {"1", "2", "3"});
                break;
            case 1:
                starting.putExtra("array", new String[] {"4", "5", "6"});
                break;
            case 2:
                starting.putExtra("array", new String[] {"7", "8", "9"});
                break;
            }
            startActivity(starting);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great.  I hate to be a bother, but I really want to understand this.  I take it that this would be in MainActivity.java.  Is that right? Any other coding or other classes to get this running.  I am new to Java.  Coming from years of .Net.

Comment: I was just updating the description. Yes this is a complete app, you can cut & paste it into `MainActivity.java` then replace every `Example` with `MainActivity`.

Comment: 95% there.  Here is what it looks like

Comment: "protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {" is an error on view, says that I should import, but when i do more of the line has a red line under it.  "setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));" is giving an error under setListAdapter. Suggesting I create a method.  Help please.

Comment: Are you extending `ListActivity`? Sounds like you are extending `Activity`.

Comment: This is a resolved topic.  @Sam:  Thanks for walking me through. Peace!

Comment: I want to know if you can tell what to put down as replacement code using the existing structure to open an activity called "Objectives.xml".  Thanks again.

Comment: What is `Objectives.xml`? Is it a list of Strings or a layout? Post this file in your question please.